# Get Date Time when an statement is true for the first time

Tags: c#

I want to capture the time when a statement is beginning to be true. But I want to capture just the first time it is true. For example in my c# code:

```
if(variable > 1){
     Console.Writeline(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
}
```

I want to print the date but not for all values bigger than but for the first value that is bigger than one.

Comment: *just the first time* the first time of what? Maybe add more of the code. As it stands this question is very unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool flag = false;
if (variable > 1)
{
    if (!flag)
    {

        Console.Writeline(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

I would recomended you to declare the flag variable outside the method, as a global one. If you do that, when you call again the method nothing will be displayed (I assume that you only want to capture it once)

-- EDIT --

Maybe it is better to check first the flag, and then the other condition. Most of the times the first condition will be enought to exit the method, so will be faster

```
bool flag = false;
    if (!flag)
    {
        if (variable > 1)
        {

            Console.Writeline(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
            flag = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can have a variable to hold whether date time is displayed or not. Once displayed it will be assigned to false.

```
public bool chk = true; // will hold the status 
if(variable > 1 && chk)
{
     chk = false;
     Console.Writeline(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach, you could use a `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
DateTime? utcNow = null;
// ...
if(variable > 1 && !utcNow.HasValue){
    utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Console.Writeline(utcNow.Value.Ticks);
}
```

This approach has the benefit that you also keep that value for later processing.